# How to convert a virtual machine to a template?

Tags: templates, virtual-machine, lab-management

I need a template in order to be able to deploy it multiple times in lab management (we don't have network isolation preconfigured). Currently we have a stored a template, but it's not configured. After deploying it and configuring it, I can't find a way to store the VM back to the library **as a template**.

According to [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ee518913(v=vs.120)) article, I am able to convert a deployed virtual machine to a stored template.

> Step 2:
>
> 1. Choose Lab Center and then choose the Lab tab.
> 2. Shut down the environment that contains the virtual machine to be stored. You can only save a virtual machine when it is in the Stopped state.
> 3. Choose Store in library on the shortcut menu of the virtual machine you want. The virtual machines appear in the right-side pane when you select the environment.

When I click on 'Lab' and right click on the machine I want to convert, there's no such option 'store in library' in the latest Lab Center.

If I launch Lab Center via Test Manager 2010, I can get this option, but it says that a newer version of TFS is used and therefore the 2010 version of Lab Center is limited in functionality.

How do I do this?

Comment: Is a programming problem?  Or a "don't know how to configure" problem?

Comment: Likely the latter. I also tried using the API, but that's a different story.

Comment: If the latter, you should probably move this to "super user", which is more concerned with managing software.  (I'm surprised the usual SO crowd hasn't closed this on you as being "not programming related"; I'm not one of that crowd, just trying to save you a bit of unnecessary paint).

Comment: That's definitely not related to superuser.

Comment: You should be able to do it using scvmm, see this article: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee702479.aspx